# Error dom is null in Ext.grid.Panel after cell click only when grid is sorted

Tags: sorting, extjs, null, typeerror, gridpanel

I've error on grid, when try to click on disabled cell. Here is the code:

```
Ext.application({
 name: 'Fiddle',
 launch: function () {
     Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
         fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
         data: [{
             name: 'Lisa',
             email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
             phone: '555-111-1224'
         }, {
             name: 'Bart',
             email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
             phone: '555-222-1234'
         }]
     });

     Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
         title: 'Simpsons',
         store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
         plugins: {
             ptype: 'cellediting',
             clicksToEdit: 1
         },
         columns: [{
             text: 'Name',
             dataIndex: 'name',
             editor: {
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 disabled: true
             }
         }, {
             text: 'Email',
             dataIndex: 'email',
             flex: 1
         }],
         height: 100,
         width: 400,
         renderTo: Ext.getBody()
     });
 }});
```

How to reproduce:

1. Click on cell "Lisa"
2. Sort by "Name" column
3. Wait 30 sec
4. Click on cell "Lisa" cell again

This error occurs:
[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUWGv.png)

Reproduced on ExtJs "7.5.0" and older.

Comment: You have disabled textfield, not a cell. May be there is a problem - disabled input could get a null value. Make it readOnly or change editor's xtype to displayfield

Comment: I have disabled textfield because I want to control it via binding. Solution with make it readOnly work good. I only ask, is there any way to disable cell?